# what magic methods does @property touch

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been trying to wrap my head around the `@property` decorator, and I think I get it, but I am very curious to know which magic methods @property (and the builtin `property`) modify. Is it just `__get__` and `__set__`, or could `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` be invoked as well? `__getattribute__`? `__setattribute__`?

As I understand it, @someproperty will modify `__get__`, @someproperty.setter will modify `__set__`, and @someproperty.deleter will modify `__del__` but I'm suspicious that I have an over simplified view on this.

I haven't been able to find this information, and I've been searching all day about properties, so hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me. Links and examples greatly appreciated.

**edit:** I wrongly was saying "call" instead of "modify," I know @property will modify magic methods. I'm just worn out from staring at this forever... thanks for the correction.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Thank you, that's EXACTLY what I was looking for. I wish I could accept that as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@property` doesn't call any of those. It defines how they work. Accessing the property then calls `__get__`, `__set__`, or `__delete__`.

```
class Foo(object):
    @property
    def x(self):
        return 4

    # If the class statement stopped here, Foo.x would have a __get__ method
    # that calls the x function we just defined, and its __set__ and __delete__
    # methods would raise errors.

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        pass

    # If the class statement stopped here, Foo.x would have usable __get__ and
    # __set__ methods, and its __delete__ method would raise an error.

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        pass

# Now Foo.x has usable __get__, __set__, and __delete__ methods.

bar = Foo()
bar.x      # Calls __get__
bar.x = 4  # Calls __set__
del bar.x  # Calls __delete__
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your title question: `__get__()`, `__set__()` and `__delete__()`,

You will find more detail on the internal workings of property [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/python-how-does-decorator-property-work) and, as has been pointed out by  dm03514, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18647583/)